# Unable to use Google Sign-in via Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented Google Sign-in via Firebase auth.

My current problem is that I keep getting the next error when my backend verified my JWT token from firebase:

*"The token violates some mandatory constraints, details:

- The token is not allowed to be used by this audience
- The token was not issued by the given users"*

Here is my code:

AuthorizationActivity's onCreate():

```
        // Initialize sign in options the client-id is copied form google-services.json file
        googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Initialize sign in client
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);

// auth button click listener
        CVGoogleAuth.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            googleSignInClient.signOut();
            googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
            Intent intent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            // Start activity for result
            startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
        });
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

AuthorizationActivity's onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 200) {
        // When request code is equal to 200 initialize task
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> signInAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        // check condition
        if (signInAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
            // When google sign in successful initialize string
            String s = "Google sign in successful";
            // Display Toast
            displayToast(s);
            // Initialize sign in account
            try {
                // Initialize sign in account
                GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = signInAccountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
                // Check condition
                if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
                    // When sign in account is not equal to null initialize auth credential
                    AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.getIdToken(), null);
                    // Check credential
                    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // Check condition
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // When task is successful redirect to profile activity display Toast
                                String token = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
                                POJOSendCode pojoC = new POJOSendCode(token);
                                // next method sending JWT from googleSignInAccount.getIdToken() to my backend server
                                gotoProfile(pojoC);
                                displayToast("Firebase authentication successful");
                            } else {
                                // When task is unsuccessful display Toast
                                displayToast("Authentication Failed :" + task.getException().getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else{
            String s = signInAccountTask.getException().getMessage();
            displayToast(s);
        }
    }
}
```

In https://console.cloud.google.com/ I have:

Android key (auto created by Firebase)

OAuth 2.0 Client IDs:

Web client (auto created by Google Service) - this is my "default_web_client_id"

Android client for com... (auto created by Google Service) - debug SHA-1

Android client for com... (auto created by Google Service) - release SHA-1

Service Accounts:
Also have one.

Of course I have put google-services.json into my project which has correct API key and other Google console credentials, of course backend has private key from https://console.firebase.google.com/.../settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk

Credentials of https://console.firebase.google and https://console.cloud.google.com/ have the same gmail account which has the "owner" role.

Backend server working with this android app with the same settings, dependencies etc like with another android app where firebase auth is working.

In Firebase menu Authentication -> Users I see users who have logged in.

My SHA-1 debug and release are correct.

I have tried to change key and get new SHA-1.

Package name in app (classes, packages, manifest) is the same that stores in Firebase project.

I have checked my token via https://jwt.io/ - signature veerified and I see the next PAYLOAD:DATA

azp - authorized party (the party to which this token is issued) - ok there is my debug credential for debug SHA-1

aud - audience (who or what token is intended to) - ok there is my webClientId (default_web_client_id) from Google console.

Hope you could help me with this problem.

Comment: Seems like I've found an answer:  `String token = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();` - this is token from Google but I need token from Firebase.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle). Otherwise, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) might help.